# React Native AWS push notifications without amplify for backend

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, aws-amplify

I am planning to use AWS push notifications for my react-native app. I am using react-native-notifications on front end (wix/react-native-notifications).

I am trying to find documentation to build the back end but I only seem to be finding amplify implementations. Is there another way to do it(just rest end points for eg.)  or am I missing something.

Any help much appreciated.

Regards

(Btw - I managed to build push notifications using aws browser console and I am able to send notifications to my app through the console but I would like to programatically add devices and invoke push notifications).